# What is the stack data structure for?

Tags: data-structures, stack

I keep reading and reading about stacks but still I do not know how to use it in real world programming! I know it is a LIFO Data Structure but how can I benefit from this? I know the POP and PUSH functions, but so what?

Comment: So we can come up with ingenious names for programming Q&A sites, like Stack Overflow. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/help-name-our-website.html

Comment: I mean: When do I need them in a real world program?

Comment: @BoltClock That's a terrible reason. :-) We could have totally just named the site `FellowWhackers.com`. (Oh, did I add an extra W?)

Comment: @MIH1406, don't your books give any use cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some places where a stack can be useful:  Any time you need to parse a string that uses parentheses for grouping, you need a stack.  If you need to traverse a tree depth-first ­- for example, to convert an internal representation of an XML file to an XML file, or to compute the value of an expression that has been given by the user - you need a stack.  Of course, in most such situations, you can avoid using it explicitly by using recursion (behind the scenes, the compiler uses a stack to implement it), but then you risk an implicit stack overflow that you can't guard against.

Comment: The first sentence of this answer is begging the question. He mentions that he already knows a stack is a LIFO data structure. That doesn't tell you why a LIFO data structure is important or useful. And it doesn't tell you why you can't use some other type of structure.

Comment: That's what's called a rhetorical device.  Did you have any comment about the rest of this answer?

Comment: @CodyGray, Thanks for using "begging the question" correctly, BTW :-) And you certainly have enough of a point that I'll go delete the first sentence.

Comment: Added "depth-first" to the tree traversal, because that is when you need a stack. If doing a bredth-frist traversal a queue is used instead.

Answer (score 7):

Every time you call a function you are using a stack! When you are doing one thing and need to go do something else, you have to "put down" what you were working on and start working on something else. Every time you finish something, you need to resume the thing you "put down" last. All the things you "put down" form a stack.

Calling a function requires "pushing" what you were doing onto a stack. Returning from a function requires "popping" what you last pushed to go back to doing it.

Comment: Actually, so long as there isn't any recursion involved, a stack is not necessary to implement function calls.  Of course, in most language environments the compiler doesn't know for sure there isn't any recursion and thus uses a stack anyway :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is used internally in your program that calls subroutines; before calling subroutines all parameters should be pushed into stack.

Also,you can use stack concept in a high-level (high-level lang) way when it is suitable.

Answer (score 0):

A common use for the stack is the shunting-yard algorithm for converting an infix expression like, 2 + 3 into prefix expressions like (+ 2 3), it is much easier for computers to evaluate prefix notation expressions.

Comment: So compilers often use this algorithm to evaluate expressions.